# How to get a set out of List[Array[String]] in Scala

Tags: scala

I am super new to scala , I have the the following code:

```
val content = List("a b","a b")
```

gives me : `List[String] = List(a b, a b)`

```
val split_data = content.map(testFile => testFile.split("\t"))
```

gives me : `List[Array[String]] = List(Array(a b), Array(a b))`

and I want to get a set out of the list, but `split_data.toSet`
 gives me: `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Array[String]] = Set(Array(a b), Array(a b))`

while I would want

```
scala.collection.immutable.Set[Array[String]] = Set(Array(a b))
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: Wait.. Don't do that.. though it outputs the expected result, but that's not what you want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, two arrays with the same values are not equal, as opposed to other collections:

```
Array(1, 2, 3) == Array(1, 2, 3) // false
List(1, 2, 3)  == List(1, 2, 3)  // true
```

This is because arrays are just Java arrays, and those don't have the same semantics as collections in functional languages. In Java, two array references are equal if they point to the same array in memory:

```
val a = Array(1, 2, 3)
a == a              // true, it's the same array
a == Array(1, 2, 3) // false, it's two different arrays
```

So, if you want to have a set of unique collections, you have to convert the arrays to Scala sequences:

```
val content = List("a b","a b")
val split_data = content.map(testFile => testFile.split("\t").toSeq)  // note the .toSeq
split_data.toSet   // set with one element
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare arrays like that as explained in the other answer. 
The easiest way around this is dedup (convert to `Set`) before `.map`:

```
content.toSet[String].map(_.split("\t"))
```

This is also a bit more efficient, because you end up `split`ing fewer strings.

Comment: `error: missing parameter type for expanded function` (Scala 2.12.6)

Comment: @jwvh hm yeah ... I have no idea why it does that :/

Comment: Ah, I got it ... that's because `toSet` takes a type parameter, gotta tell it explicitly, that you want `String`.